# drawing a circle using bezier path swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to draw a circle, which is in my custom table view cell class, based on dates. E.g. I have two date objects; date1 and date2 respectively. The closer date1 becomes closer to date2, the circle should become more completed towards being a full circle. When the amount of days is 0, there should be a full circle etc.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(-Double.pi/2)
    let endAngle = CGFloat(-Double.pi/2 + Double.pi * Double(2) * Double(components.day!) * 0.1)

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 80,y: 80), radius: CGFloat(60), startAngle:startAngle , endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    var colour = UIColor.green.cgColor

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = colour
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0

    cell.progressView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

The `components.day!` is the amount of days between the 2 dates. 
But the circle that gets drawn does not correlate to the the amount of days. I'm guessing I've got my angles wrong but not sure why

Comment: Can you be more clear on "does not correlate to the the amount of days"?

Comment: Your requirement isn't very clear. When the date difference is 0 days the circle should be full. That's fine. But how many days represent a half circle? How many represent an empty circle? And is `components.day` the number of days between the two dates?

Comment: @rmaddy a half circle should basically represent a 10 days. an empty circle should represent 20 days or more? and yes, `components.days` is the number of days between the two dates

Comment: @George_E_2 sometimes when the difference is 1 day, the circle is a quarter when the difference is around 6-7, it's stil a quarter circle. So the circle doesn't necessarily reflect the number of days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the requirement that if the date difference (`components.day`) is 20 or more, the circle should be empty. If the difference is 0 then the circle should be complete. So the first thing you need to do is to compute the percentage full based on `components.day`.

```
let percentFull = 1 - Double(min(components.day!, 20)) / 20
```

Then you can calculate the angles:

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2) // top of circle
let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * Double.pi * percentFull

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 80, y: 80), radius: 60, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Also, if I wanted the circle to be adaptable for any given date e.g. if the difference between the dates is 5 and it's currently on the 4th day, the circle should be 80% complete whilst if the difference between the dates is 10 and it's currently on the 7th day, the circle should be 70% complete.. how would I go on about doing that?

Comment: You just need to update the calculation of `percentFull`. Everything else would stay the same.

Comment: I may be overcomplicating it.. The way I'm thinking to do it is to calculate the number of seconds since 1970 from date1, and doing the same thing for date2, and then get the current time and see how many seconds its been since 1970 and then draw it based on the how far the current number of seconds lies between the two ranges..

Comment: You can directly get the difference in seconds between two dates. No need to get 1970 involved.

Comment: I am not sure how to go on about doing that. This is what I've got for percentFull: `1 - Double(min(currentTimeSince1970, startDateSince1970)) / endDateSince1970`..

Comment: I've tried a few things but none of them have given decent results. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not be doing anything with seconds. Stick to days. Sounds like you should post another question specific to calculating a percentage from some dates.