# Calculate percentage difference of 2 dates

Tags: ios, swift

I need to calculate the completion percentage between two dates. I have two dates: `date1` and `date2`. When `date1` catches up to `date2`, it should be 100%. Any days the current date is after `date1`, there should be some progress. E.g. everyday until `date2` is met, there should be some sort of progress.

I am having difficulty in finding the percentage of two dates and their differences.

This is related to
[drawing a circle using bezier path swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281234/drawing-a-circle-using-bezier-path-swift/50293685#50293685)

So currently, I have the following:

```
let percentFull = 1 - Double(min(Int(components.day!), 20) / 20)
```

Comment: This is not what I suggested. This question should only be about how to determine the percentage given your two dates and their difference. This question makes no mention of the requirements you stated in your earlier comments.

Comment: I've updated your question to focus on your actual question. But you still have not included the information you put in comments in the other question. Update this question to explain your examples of having two dates that are 10 days apart and it is now the 7th day.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `DateInterval`, it can do most of the work for you:

```
let duration = DateInterval(start: startDate, end: endDate).duration
let complete = DateInterval(start: startDate, end: currentDate).duration
let percentComplete = complete / duration
```

If you want it to be in the form of 0-100 rather than 0-1:

```
let adjustedPercent = percentComplete * 100.0
```

Comment: why not simply `let duration = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)`?

Comment: That would do it too, I thought of date interval first is the only reason I went that way.